# pipe does not exist on type observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have upgraded my application from angular 4 to angular 6. I am getting error pipe does not exist on type observable . I have seen documentation where it says you need to pipe before calling flatMap but not sure why I am still getting syntactical error. Could somebody tell me if anything has changed in angular 6

```
import { of, map, catchError, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    logout(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this._proxy.logout().pipe(flatMap(ret => ret.data.success ? this.doLogout() : of(false)));
    }
```

Comment: whats `this._proxy.logout()` ??

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules and installing it again. Make sure it is version 6 installed.

Comment: have you updated also you `rxjs` version?

Comment: in my package.json it shows  "rxjs": "^6.3.2",

Comment: Could you provide the full text of the error or a screenshot? It is very important.

Comment: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<ApiResult<LogoutResponse>>'.

Comment: I recommend delete node_modules and reinstall it, package.json does not guarantee that the package with such version is really installed.